# Loading Webform Content into Select Box

Tags: forms, entities, webforms

So I have a Webform called "Department". It contains "Marketing" and "IT" as submissions.

I have another webform called "Person". It is a form that contains a dropdown. This dropdown should be loaded with values from the "department" Webform data.

So I add a new webform, and add a "Entity Select" called "Person Department".

I go to build, in "Person Department", in the "entity references settings", I select "Webform Submission" as the "type of item to reference", and select "Department" as Bundle.

However, when I go to my "Person" form, the drop down is loaded with Person:webform submission5.

How can I display the value of the Webform data in "department", not the key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to use a View for the 'Select Entity' element's reference method but you might run into [Issue #2174633: View output is not used for entityreference options](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2174633)

[image]